# Box on the wall problem (basic trig)

Tags: trigonometry

I am having a bit of trouble with this problem:

[image]

The answer is :

> H = L sin $\theta$ + W cos $\theta$

I understand that L sin $\theta$ equals the length of leg `a` in this image:

[image]

However, how can one derive the second addend: W cos $\theta$? How can I solve this problem from start to end?

Comment: The lower angle made where the box touches the wall is $\theta$ less than a right angle, and since angles on a straight line sum to two right angles then you know that the upper angle made where the box touches the wall must be $\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

I added a few things to your figure. I hope this helps you see why $b = W\cos\theta$. Of course, you need to show that the angle I marked as $\color{blue}\theta$ is indeed $\theta$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little more attempts on your behalf would be useful to those answering, but nevertheless, this is how I would approach the problem:

Firstly, you're right that the length of $a$ is needed, but there are also other values that are required, so I have adjusted the diagram to indicate these values:

[image]

Now firstly, let me elaborate on why the top left angle is equal to $\theta$. Let the corner where the wall meets the floor equal $90^\circ$, hence the angle at the top of this triangle is now $180-90-\theta=90-\theta$, given that the internal angles of a triangle sum to produce $180^\circ$. Furthermore, since the angles at the corners of the box equals $90^\circ$, the angle formed above the corner of the box is equal to $180-90-(90-\theta)=90-90+\theta=\theta$, since an angle on a straight line = $180^\circ$

Now, side $a$, as you have stated, is equal to $L\sin\theta$, and then $b$ is equal to:

$\displaystyle\frac{b}{\sin(90-\theta)}=\frac{W}{\sin(90)}$

$b=W\sin(90-\theta)$

and then, using the trigonometric identity, $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$,

$b=W[\sin(90)\cos(\theta)-\cos(90)\sin(\theta)]$

$b=W[\cos(\theta)-0]$

$b=W\cos(\theta)$

and since $H=a+b$,

$H = L\sin\theta+W\cos\theta$

*QED*

To be very honest, during my time at high school, understanding the trigonometric identities wasn't considered "basic trigonometry" but either way, they are needed in this context.

Comment: You don't need the formula for $\sin(a-b)$ to know that $\sin(90-\theta)=\cos\theta$. The definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$, along with the sum of angles in a right triangle will tell you that immediately: using sine with one angle is the same as using cosine with the other angle. So I would say this is still basic trigonometry.

Comment: I suppose this is true. The only reason why I said I wouldn't classify it as "basic" is because of my own educational background. What's basic to some people might be complex to others, you know?

Comment: Well, you are right about that. Still, I think it should be basic to be able to look at that figure that you've made (or the one that I've made), and see that the $b$ is $W\cos\theta$, without ever involving $\sin$. Setting up $\frac{b}{\sin(90-\theta)}=\frac{W}{\sin(90)}$ seems overly complicated, and I can't even tell immediately how you got it.

Comment: Well I guess the author of the question wasn't immediately able to see that. And a more rigorous proof behind why $\sin(90-\theta) =\cos(\theta)$ might just help justify seeing this.